# control flow with anypoint studio// using choice

Tags: mule

i want to do a test on a flow with anypoint, so the idea is to test if a response coming from a http flow is ok (response from a server who will send a push to a device). If the response is yes there is nothing to do, if not we have to send a message to a number phone.
So for the elements i was thinking about http connector, and a flow control: choice.is that all what i need? there is any other suggestion? and finaly how to configure choice element.

Comment: This should be pretty easy to accomplish using Studio. Please try it and share the results if you encounter any problems. You can check the documentation as Anirban mentioned or even look for examples here: https://www.mulesoft.com/library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the Choice to know how to configure it :- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Choice+Flow+Control+Reference

You could have atleast tried it in a flow and shared it here so that we could have suggested you on what you attempted

Http inbound connector and Choice router is what you need , remaining elements depends on what device or end system you are planning to push the data

Comment: Thank you for replying, so I am currently working on my example, I put the http connector who get the response from the web service. but the problem is how to test if sent = ok how to extract attribute sent from json what I should use.

Comment: Json elements can be using Json-to-Object transformer and then using MEL expression

Answer (score 0):

Use Http connector, choice router and a Java component which can sen SMS though SMS gateway.

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. While this answer may be correct, it doesn't add to the currently selected answer.